Interaction between filtrations and module relations
I'm struggling a little with how filtrations interact with module relations. Some rationale would be amazing, please.

Setup: let $R[G]$ be an algebra over a principal ideal domain $R$, and let $V$ be a finitely-generated $R$-module, generated by $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$. Let $\sum_{i=1}^m n_i = n$ be an ordered partition of $n$ and suppose that $V$ has a filtration $$0 = F^0M \subset F^1M \subset \cdots \subset F^m M = M$$ where each $F^i M$ is the $R$-module generated by the first $\sum_{j=1}^i n_j$ elements of the $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$. Note that then $F^{i+1}M/F^{i}M$ is the $R$-module of rank $n_{i+1}$ generated by the $(i+1)^{\text{st}}$ 'set' of the $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$.
Consider the $R[G]$-module extension $\mathcal{M}:=R[G] \otimes_{R} M$, which comes with a natural filtration $F^i \mathcal{M}=R[G]\otimes_R F^i M$. For $\mathcal{R}$ an $R[G]$-submodule of 'relations', consider the quotient $$\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{R}} := \mathcal{M} / \mathcal{R}.$$
Questions:

How can we most 'naturally' define a filtration $F^i\mathcal{M}_\mathcal{R}$ on $\mathcal{M}_\mathcal{R}$ that reflects our original filtration $F^iM$ on $M$?

Must it follow that each $R[G]$-submodule of $\mathcal{M}_\mathcal{R}$ is of the shape $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{R}^\prime$ where $\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathcal{R}^\prime$ extends the original set of relations (in a sense restricting the module down further)?

For some other $R[G]$-submodule of relations $\widetilde{\mathcal{R}}$, is it true that $\mathcal{M}_\mathcal{R} / \widetilde{\mathcal{R}} = \mathcal{M} / (\mathcal{R} + \widetilde{\mathcal{R}})$?

Does $F^i \mathcal{M}_\mathcal{R}:= F^i \mathcal{M}/(\mathcal{R} \cap F^i \mathcal{M})$ work as a filtration on $\mathcal{M}_\mathcal{R}$? I have seen this idea being used elsewhere, but it does not seem intuitive to me.



Thanks in advance as ever,
M
